# Crontable not work when I set curl delete elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, cron

I have script  "delete_elk_index "which include :

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://ip:9200/index0'
```

It can work when I manually execute but  don't work when set it in crontab.

The crontab log is:

```
MAIL (mailed 55 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
```

I have already see the [https://superuser.com/questions/1478754/crontab-job-log-message-shows-a-error-status-0x004b-from-mta012][1]

Then I change my crontab :

```
 */1 *  *   *   *     /root/delete_elk_index.sh>/dev/null 2>&1
```

The crontab log became:

```
 CMD (/root/delete_elk_index.sh)
```

But the the index is not deleted.
How can I set in crontab?

Answer (score 0):

edit script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl --request DELETE 'http://ip:9200/index0'
```

also maybe you need to edit crontab like below:

```
 */1 *  *   *   *   root  /root/delete_elk_index.sh>/dev/null 2>&1
```